# UIView bounds with top bar

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, interface-builder

When creating a UIView with a navigation bar in interface builder, the top bar takes some space, but the view still has the same size.  This mean that the bottom of the view is not visible.

Is there a way to get the "visible size" of a UIView?  I would like to show a subview at the bottom of the screen, but part of the subview is hidden since the parent view goes "below" the screen.

Comment: Are you asking about how to make it size right in IB or how to get and set the size in code?

Comment: I'm asking about getting the size in code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use the 'struts-and-springs' control in IB to set your base view to be full-justified. Then it will auto-resize. Once you do this, you can just use the view.bounds property to access its visible area.

Answer (score 2):

You should use Ben Gottlieb's solution but in terms of calculating the visible area of a view named "`view`", you could probably use:

```
CGRect viewBoundsInWindow =
    [[[UIApplication sharedApplication] keyWindow] convertRect:view.layer.visibleRect fromView:view];
```